# WordPress вывод постов состоящих в двух категориях

Tags: php, wordpress

На главной странице сайта свой уникальный дизайн. Для его функциональности на главной нужно вывести популярные или важные(featured) посты из каждой категории, лежащей в родителе, который я указываю.

Хочу заранее сказать что я ищу совет, а не решение. На какие функции стоит обратить внимание? Как это сделать иначе? Что не так? И т.д.

Дам пример:

```
- Родитель 1
   - Потомок1
   - Потомок2
   - Потомок3 ...
- Featured
```

То есть нужно что бы посты, выведенные на главной одновременно состояли в 'Родитель 1' и `Featured` и выводились не более 6-ти штук на категорию.

Это еще не все. Так же я предполагаю создать приоритет. Под каждым постом в featured будет указан приоритет(от 1-6) и в зависимости от этого будет выбираться очередность выводимых в блоке постов. Это будет реализовано через дополнительные поля (get_post_meta).

На данный момент код простой:

```
$prt=get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>0,'child_of'=>12,'orderby'=> 'id','title_li'=>''));
...
$query = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>$tid,'showposts'=>'6'));
```

Вся его задача вытащить все категории из родителя, после чего следующая строчка вытащит из каждой по 6 постов. Дело в том что 6 последних постов и сортировки по приоритетам у них нет.

Я боюсь что нужно будет писать очень большой и громоздкой код с проверками на посты и дополнительными запросами для такой задачи, может вы знаете примеры попроще? Может можно/нужно составить вовсе чистый SQL запрос где это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еcли я правильно понял:

```
foreach ($cat_ids as $cat_id) {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'category__and' => array($cat_id, $feature_id),
        'showposts' => '6',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'priority'
    ));
    // Дальше Loop по сценарию
}
```

В ролях:

- `$cat_ids` - массив с ID подкатегорий категории "Родитель 1";
- `$feature_id` - ID категории "Featured";
- `'priority'` - ключ дополнительного поля приоритета поста.